# UITextView not being shown in iOS versions below 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, xib

I have a strange issue where a UITextView from a .xib file is not shown in iOS versions below 7.1. In iOS >= 7.1 everything is fine, both for 3.5 and 4-inch screens. Is it some iOS 7.0 bug that I'm not aware of that got fixed in 7.1?

Comment: Autolayout? Missing constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was a tricky one. By reading through some questions of the time of the switch from iOS 6 to iOS 7 I figured that setting `[self.textView setScrollEnabled:NO]` solved the problem in iOS 7.0, but apparently this 'feature' got fixed in 7.1, so having that line of code broke everything in 7.1, the outer view didn't even load. So I had to include a version check to support iOS 7.0 and 7.1 at the same time:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.1f) {
    [self.textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}
```

It would also most likely not work on iOS 6, but my app doesn't support it anyway.